# How to model a computer mouse?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

i am trying to model a computer mouse similar to this:

[image]

I have not found ANY tutorials on how to create a computer mouse, I have tried box modelling it, but failed because i could not do the side view. I have yet to find a tutorial on modelling a computer mouse. I have tried various methods, none have met my needs. i know there is no set way to do this, but i would like a method or step-by-step guide on how to model this, as this is a complex shape.

**EDIT**: My problem has still not been resolved, not just creating the base mesh, but a more detailed answer would be nice. Please..

Comment: Please use google. There are Blender tutorials about creating computer mouse.

Comment: Please detail what you tried and why it din't work.

Comment: Did you try googling or YouTube for tutorials ? This is a very broad question. Modelling a mouse like this uses numeral methods including booleans and beveling. You have to be familiar with booleans (or precise box modelling), to achieve this.

Comment: have not found a tutorial on mouse modelling yet.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't find any ? a quick YouTube search brings up dozens of tutorials on mouse modelling in blender.

Comment: all i see are timelapses, not 20 minute in-depth tutorials..

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it:

Create a cylinder with 90° rotation on the y-axis.

Stretch the cylinder:

[image: Cylinder]

Use the `knife` tool (<kbd>K</kbd>) to cut the cylinder like this:

[image: Knife]

(Do this on both sides)

Select the loop created by your cut:

[image: Selection]

(Wireframe used to show selection)

`Select loop inner region` (search for this by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>)

Enter face selection mode and `Select`>`Inverse`.

Delete faces (<kbd>X</kbd>). Select the edges of the hole and make a face (<kbd>F</kbd>).

Select the edges that form arcs (you could do this by selecting the side faces, converting to edge selection, and deselecting the bottom edges):

[image: Selection]

Bevel these faces (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>). Adjust the bevel settings as desired:

[image: Bevel]

Now that you have the general shape of the mouse, you can use [proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html) to create the curves in the surface.